# Problems with in Fisher exact test: results by fisher.test and oddratio function of epitools package

Tags: r, fishers-exact-test

This is my data

```
mydata <- matrix(c(86,1,14,0), nrow = 2, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
```

When using fisher.test in R give

```
fisher.test(mydata)

Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  mydata
p-value = 1
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
   0.0000 241.4466
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
         0
```

But using oddratios function in epitools show

```
library(epitools)

oddsratio(mydata)

error in uniroot(function(or) {：f() values at end points not of opposite sign
```

Which result should I use? And can the error of oddratios be fixed?

Comment: You can use fisher.test() or twoby2() from package "Epi". Both will work. Since your sample oddsratio is equal to zero, I don't think you'll get anything from the function oddsratio(), since the function uniroot() is showing error. You can see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38961221/uniroot-solution-in-r for the error in uniroot().

Comment: Why are you looking for another test/implementation? The confidence interval for the odds ratio from the Fisher's exact test is [0,241]. This tells you that your data are not informative (about the probabilities in the second column).